# Excel VBA - Set variable to value of formula

Tags: vba, excel, variables

Is there anyway to set a variable in VBA to the result/value of a formular.
I need it to calculate the result in VBA and not in a cell.

```
Variable1 = "=SUBTOTAL(3,INDIRECT('New Sheet 1'!A3:A4500))"
Variable2 = "=SUMPRODUCT(--ISERR('New Sheet 1'!J3:J4000))"
Variable3 = "=COUNTBLANK('New Sheet 1'!P2:P4000)"
```

Already here I see some issues using the '-marks.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Use Evaluate

```
Variable1 = Application.Evaluate("SUBTOTAL(3,INDIRECT('New Sheet 1'!A3:A4500))")
Variable2 = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--ISERR('New Sheet 1'!J3:J4000))")
Variable3 = Application.Evaluate("COUNTBLANK('New Sheet 1'!P2:P4000)")
```

Or you can use the short hand for Evaluate:

```
Variable1 = [SUBTOTAL(3,INDIRECT('New Sheet 1'!A3:A4500))]
Variable2 = [SUMPRODUCT(--ISERR('New Sheet 1'!J3:J4000))]
Variable3 = [COUNTBLANK('New Sheet 1'!P2:P4000)]
```

`[]` used this way is shorthand for `Application.Evaluate` And with the formulas you are using it will work.

If your formulas contained a concatenated string with variables then the shorthand method would not work, and the `Application.Evaluate` would need to be spelled out with the quotes